# Merged Shapefile with different Styles

Tags: labeling, rule-based, mergeshapes

QGIS Zurich 3.18.2 Need to pass on a Shapefile to A Nother. There were three Layers each with assigned Label Style (saved) as can be seen[image: original layers]

Yes I know I have a lot more work to do on the Label placement/conflicts.
I then successfully merged these three shapefiles (adding a Unique Field Name for each original Layer) and have tried to setup a Rule Based Labels for each of the selected Unique attribute data, selecting then Load Style for that data BUT each time it reverts to a Single Label style
[image: merged layers but Rule Based failed]
Am I going about it wrong or is it not possible?

Comment: Your saved styles **are** single labels - hence the style switches from rule-based to single. You need to recreate the original labels for each rule.

Comment: You said you created the desired labels for single layers, without rules. Hence your saved styles contain only single labels, not rule based labels.

Comment: so I should be able to load in from the Merge Layer the Style created when a single layer then save that within the Merged Layer, do that for each. Then set up a RuleBased Style calling on the styles saved within the Merged Layer for each of the elements. 
I dont have to re-create each Label Style specifically within the Rule Based element, which is what I read you implied..

Comment: That's not how it works.

Comment: so I went the long way round and re-created each style as in the single layers in the new combined merged layer, a fag but got there